# Makefile missing include path Although the path exists and defined

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

i have make file which i try to make them generic 
but it keeps to compline it missing include directory 
this is the makefile :

```
CXX=g++
CPPFAGS= -Wall -O0 -g -std=c++14
INCLUDES = -I/home/vagrant/libuv/include -Isrc
LIBS_DIRS = -L/home/vagrant/libuv/build
LDFLAGS= -lssl -lcrypto
LIB_STATIC = -Wl,--no-as-needed -Bstatic -luv_a -ldl -lpthread
SOURCE = $(wildcard echo.cpp) \
         $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ = $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)
DEP = $(OBJ:.o=.d)
TARGET = myproj


$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS_DIRS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB_STATIC)

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ) $(TARGET)
cleandep:
        rm -f $(DEP)

.PHONY:all clean cleandep
```

when i make : make -n :

```
   make -n
g++    -c -o echo.o echo.cpp
g++    -c -o src/base64.o src/base64.cpp
g++    -c -o src/Server.o src/Server.cpp
g++    -c -o src/sha1.o src/sha1.cpp
g++    -c -o src/Client.o src/Client.cpp
g++  -I/home/vagrant/libuv/include -Isrc -o myproj echo.o src/base64.o src/Server.o src/sha1.o src/Client.o -L/home/vagrant/libuv/build -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,--no-as-needed -Bstatic -luv_a -ldl -lpthread
```

when i invoke make , im getting this error:

```
 make
g++    -c -o echo.o echo.cpp
In file included from src/Server.h:9:0,
                 from echo.cpp:1:
src/Client.h:6:10: fatal error: uv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <uv.h>
          ^~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [echo.o] Error 1
```

but the uv do exist in : /home/vagrant/libuv/include

Comment: It makes no sence to specify the include path for a *linker* invocation. You need to specify one for *compiler* invocations. You are not doing that.

Comment: can you please hint me where to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no rule to build your object files: you've only defined a rule to link your object files into a final executable.  As mentioned in the comments, adding `$(INCLUDES)` into that recipe is useless because header file directories are only used during compiling (creating object files) not linking (converting object files and libraries into executables).

Because you haven't defined your own rule to build object files, you're using make's built-in rule.  But make's built-in rule doesn't know anything about a variable named `INCLUDES`, so that variable is not used during compilation.  You can easily see this by looking at the compiler commands generated by make.

You need to either (a) create your own rule for compiling object files that uses your personal make variables, or (b) use the normal [built-in variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables) that make expects to be used with its built-in rules.

For (b), as described in the manual, you should take your current `CPPFAGS` [sic] variable and rename it to `CXXFLAGS`, take your current `INCLUDES` variable and rename it `CPPFLAGS`, take your current `LIBS_DIRS` variable and rename it `LDFLAGS`, and take your current `LDFLAGS` variable and rename it to `LDLIBS`.

Also just to note, you have `DEPS` etc. but there is nothing in your makefile that does anything with them or to create them so they're useless.